# want Calendar to stay open in its own window - HTC Evo

Tags: calendar

Working fine with Exchange sync of agenda view of Outlook Calendar.  How do I keep the Calendar **open in its own slide window** without having to push the "Calendar" icon?

Comment: Errr...Android doesn't really have a concept of "windows". Do you mean a widget?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the calendar widget and put it on the home screen. The widget doesn't really have any options, if what it supplies you isn't enough information, you will need to get a 3rd party app that has more info.

I use [Business Calendar Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mikado.bizcalpro). It shows an agenda widget and can display events from multiple calendars. There is a free version, but it is well worth the ~$5.00.